# Having react-router 3.0.x with configured basename working with react-router-redux 4.0.x

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

I've the following env:

```
"react": "^15.4.2",
"react-redux": "^5.0.3",
"react-router": "^3.0.2",
"react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
```

Migrate to react-router 4 *is not an option* in this project.

With the following configuration my application is working properly (that means: my `dispatch(push('/foo'))` are working, performing a browser URL change *and* a redux store `@@reouter/LOCATION_CHANGE`):

```js
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { Router, useRouterHistory } from 'react-router';

const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history} routes={routes} />
  </Provider>,
  rootEl
);
```

Issues started when I need to add a `basename` to the routing URL.

I found some different ways of doing this. Follow one of the test I did:

```js
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Router, useRouterHistory } from 'react-router';
//import { createHistory } from 'history';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';


//const browserHistory = useRouterHistory(createHistory)({
//  basename: config.historyBasename,
//});

const browserHistory = useRouterHistory(createBrowserHistory)({
  basename: config.historyBasename,
});

const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history} routes={routes} />
  </Provider>,
  rootEl
);
```

Whatever configuration I try, my dispatches of `push` from `react-router-redux` now stopped working: I still see a browser URL change, but no change in my store.

Is possible to have `react-router-redux` working with a `basename` with the version listed above?

Comment: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux/issues/414#issuecomment-228582441

Comment: To answer the last question of whether you CAN, yes. I have it working, but your config is the same as mine.

Comment: @DanBalaban d'oh! And yours `push` are triggering LOCATION_CHANGE?

Comment: Yep, been using the config in production since late February without issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the end we found that there's no issue with the react-router configuration.

The issue was in the `Route` configuration. A missing slash in front of the `path` parameter was leading to the bug.